# arima estimate validation through arima.sim

Tags: r

This is out of my curiosity trying to compare time series input to an ARMA model and reconstructed series after an ARMA estimate is obtained. These are the steps I am thinking:

1. construct simulation time series

   ```
   arma.sim <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=c(0.9),ma=c(0.2)),n = 100)
   ```
2. estimate the model from arma.sim, assuming we know it is a (1,0,1) model

   ```
   arma.est1 <- arima(arma.sim, order=c(1,0,1))
   ```

   also say we get arma.est1 in this form, which is close to the original (0.9,0,0.2):

   ```
   Coefficients:
    ar1     ma1  intercept
   0.9115  0.0104    -0.4486
   s.e.  0.0456  0.1270     1.1396

   sigma^2 estimated as 1.15:  log likelihood = -149.79,  aic = 307.57
   ```
3. If I try to reconstruct another time series from arma.est1, how do I incorporate intercept or s.e. in arima.sim? Something like this doesn't seem to work well because arma.sim and arma.rec are far off:

   ```
   arma.rec <- arima.sim(n=100, list(ar=c(0.9115),ma=c(0.0104)))
   ```

Normally we use predict() to check the estimate. But is this a legit way to look at the estimate?

Comment: If you're asking about statistical validity (ie "legit"), that's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. If you need help from a statistician rather than a programmer, you should post to [stats.se] instead. Otherwise, can you make your specific programming question here clearer?

Comment: Cool, I didn't know Cross Validated. Thanks for pointing that out. In fact, I may have found answers from there.